# Logging pulls from a repository with Git

Tags: git

We have a bare repository on a remote server that people can connect to (using their own usernames) and clone/pull the code. I know there is no hook on the remote side that is called for pulls/fetches, but we would like to track who pulls the code and when.

Does anybody out there have any idea how to record when the code is pulled and the username that did it?

Putting a hook client-side that sends info to the remote server on merge or something isn't a viable option because that requires the user to set it up in their repository. For better or worse, our manager wants to know who is and is not keeping up to date on the code changes and people who aren't keeping up to date certainly won't take extra steps so everybody knows about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could audit file access to the .git/objects directory in the remote. This assumes you are using ssh to connect to the remote.